# How do I find the number of days in each quarter between two dates in python / pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have an arbitrary long list of start and end dates. The dates can cover single but also multiple quarters, and can be abroad years as well. Per start and end date, I need to find the amount of days spent in a quarter, for each quarter - quarters with 0 days spent in, do not need to be listed.

I am working with pandas at the moment but as I see it, this would need to be solved via python, iterating through every row of my data frame, and taking the start and end date, to retrieve the information I am looking for.

Example:

```
start = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,1,1))
end = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,6,30))
```

Aimed result:

```
{
'2024Q1': 90, 
'2024Q2': 90
}
```

For easy cases I was able to solve it with simple if-else combinations, but the more complex the date-combinations got, e.g. spanning multiple quarters and also years, I found myself struggeling.

Please see here some more examples:

```
start = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2023,10,17))
end = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,4,12))
```

Can someone hint me into the right direction / support me here and explain a solution that should give me the result I would like to see?

Here is what I tried so far, but have a strong feeling that it is not going into the right direction.

```
import datetime as dt

og_start = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,1,1))
og_end = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,6,30))

year = start_date.year
stats = {}
date_hold = 0


while year <= end_date.year:
        
    print(year)
    start = og_start
    end = og_end
    
    qq = {
        f"{year}Q1" : [pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,1,1)),pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,3,31))],
        f"{year}Q2" : [pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,4,1)),pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,6,30))],
        f"{year}Q3" : [pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,7,1)),pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,9,30))],
        f"{year}Q4" : [pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,10,1)),pd.Timestamp(dt.date(year,12,31))],
    }    
    
    
    if (start >= qq[f"{year}Q1"][0]) & (start <= qq[f"{year}Q1"][1]) & (end <= qq[f"{year}Q1"][1]) & (end >= qq[f"{year}Q1"][0]):
        print(1)
        diff = end - start
        stats[f"{year}Q1"] = diff
    
    if (start >= qq[f"{year}Q1"][0]) & (start <= qq[f"{year}Q1"][1]) & (end > qq[f"{year}Q1"][1]):
        print(2)
        diff = qq[f"{year}Q1"][1] - start
        stats[f"{year}Q1"] = diff
        start = qq[f"{year}Q2"][0]

    if (start >= qq[f"{year}Q2"][0]) & (start <= qq[f"{year}Q2"][1]) & (end < qq[f"{year}Q2"][1]):
        pass
        
    if (start >= qq[f"{year}Q2"][0]) & (start <= qq[f"{year}Q2"][1]) & (end >= qq[f"{year}Q2"][1]):
        print(3)
        diff = qq[f"{year}Q2"][1] - start
        stats[f"{year}Q2"] = diff
        start = qq[f"{year}Q3"][0] if qq[f"{year}Q3"][0] <= og_start else og_start 

    year += 1
    
print("start date: ", start)
print("end date: ", end)
print(stats)
```

I expected this code to return me a dict of quarters and the number of days spent in each, but it only works for easy and straight forward date combinations, cross-year date combinations are already messing the result up by a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by 'days spent'? Do you mean number of days in each quarter within the time range?

Comment: Correct. As shown in my example, I would like to understand the number of days per quarter / range between the two dates. Adjusted the heading to make it clearer.

Comment: Is this an assignment or are you looking for a generic solution?

Comment: Also please clarify how exactly you want to count the days. I count 90 or 91 depending on whether the initial day is included.

Comment: Yes, the initial day should be included. What is the difference between an assignment or a generic solution for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can simply use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) to create the days, [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) to convert to quarterly period and count the days with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
start = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,1,1))
end = pd.Timestamp(dt.date(2024,6,30))

pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D').to_period('Q').value_counts(sort=False)
```

Output:

```
2024Q1    91
2024Q2    91
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: count, dtype: int64
```

For an output as dictionary:

```
out = (pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D').to_period('Q')
         .astype(str).value_counts(sort=False).to_dict()
      )
```

Output:

```
{'2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 91}
```

Output with the second example:

```
{'2023Q4': 76, '2024Q1': 91, '2024Q2': 12}
```

##### more efficient option

Alternatively, a more efficient option might be to generate an Index of the start and end dates with the quarters in-between and to perform a `diff`:

```
idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='Q').union([start, end], sort=True)
# DatetimeIndex(['2023-10-17', '2023-12-31', '2024-03-31', '2024-04-12'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

out = dict(zip(idx.to_period('Q').astype(str)[1:], idx.diff().days[1:]))
# {'2023Q4': 75.0, '2024Q1': 91.0, '2024Q2': 12.0}
```

*Note that the two approaches have a slightly different count on the boundaries. It depends whether or not you want to include the starting day. But it's easy to correct once you know what you want.*

Comment: Thanks, the initial day should be included. I do understand your solution but struggle to get a clear understanding of the "more efficent option".

Comment: @Binchentso for the second option I ask `date_range` to generate the dates of all quarter ends between start and end. Then I compute the difference in days between the successive dates. I think the first approach is fine even if you have thousands of days, but it's uselessly generating all individual days, thus the increased efficiency of the second approach.